# Why number of dirty pages is always 0 on 2.6?

Tags: linux, kernel, proc

In `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt` i've found the string:

```
Table 1-3: Contents of the statm files (as of 2.6.8-rc3)
.....................................................................
dt       number of dirty pages          (always 0 on 2.6)
```

this info is also could be get from `/proc/<PID>/statm`, the last column.

So, why `dt` is always 0? Does "on 2.6" means "on 2.6 higher"? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably an obsolete concept, but the field cannot be removed because some programs parse `statm` and expect the field to be present. Did you try searching http://lwn.net/ ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, no results. I also think that way, that it's obsolet. Seems like the only way to get dirty memory is to parse `/proc/42/smaps` and sum up shared and private dirty -- but I'm not sure this is accurate enough...